# javascript handling confirm if user selects to not allow prompting

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

on my wordpress site i have a table with buttons in each row that make ajax calls.  each button confirms with the user before taking any action.  after clicking the button and confirming more than once there's a checkbox in the confirm window that the user can click to prevent the site from prompting them again to confirm.

[image]

when i select this check box the next button i click in the table doesn't work because i have some logic in my javascript that is checking if the confirmation was true or not.  any ideas or techniques on how i can code around this?  i would like for the user to confirm their choice at least once, but i'm ok with them selecting to not be prompted again.

```
            var confirmMessage='Press Ok to mark complete.';
            var x = confirm(confirmMessage); 
            if (x == true) {
                $.post(my_ajax_obj.ajax_url, {     //POST request
                    _ajax_nonce: my_ajax_obj.nonce, //nonce
                    action: "all_table_complete",        //action
                    row_result_id: trid              //data
                }, function(data) {                //callback
                    var retractTdSearchFor = "retract_button_" + trid;     
                    this2.closest('td').innerHTML = data;           //insert server response
                    document.getElementById(retractTdSearchFor).innerHTML = "Completed"; // should find ignore td with same result id
                });
            } // if (x == true)
            else
            {
                // the user did not click ok. 
            }
```

Comment: Well if you are going to prompt so many times, you might want to rethink using prompt and making your own confirmation dialog.

Comment: That checkbox is intented to block any confirm()s to allow you to prevent spammy sites from doing it
Either do what epascarello said or just make a checkbox to confirm in your html

Comment: ok, thanks.  would i use something like https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation to create my own confirmation?  i'm new to javascript.